# MemoryCache TryGetValue always returning false

Tags: c#, blazor, memorycache

I am trying to create a auto sign-in function in my blazor web app. The web app opens to a empty screen called ResolveAuthorization that looks like this:

```cs
@page "/"
@layout EmptyLayout
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IMemoryCache MemoryCache

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized() {
        base.OnInitialized();

        string? token;
        bool tokenPresent = MemoryCache.TryGetValue("token", out token); // Here the token is null

        if ( tokenPresent )
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("menu");
        else
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("signin");
    }
}
```

The sign-in screen has calls a service when submitted, the class with this method in this service looks like this:

```cs
public class AuthorizationService : IAuthorizationService {
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public AuthorizationService(HttpClient httpClient, IMemoryCache memoryCache) {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public async Task<(bool, string?)> Signin(SigninDto input) {
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/user/signin", input);
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if ( response.IsSuccessStatusCode == false ) {
            return (false, ErrorDto.FromJson(content)!.ErrorMessage);
        }

        TokenDto token = TokenDto.FromJson(content)!;

        _memoryCache.Set("token", token.Token, token.Role == "Admin" ? TimeSpan.FromDays(1) : TimeSpan.FromDays(30));

        string? foundToken;
        _memoryCache.TryGetValue("token", out foundToken); // Here the token is not null

        return (true, token.Token);
    }
}
```

For extra information. In my startup I register my caching and AuthorizationService like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationService, AuthorizationService>();
```

My problem is that in the TryGetValue in the ResolveAuthorizationScreen always returns null and I don't know why. I assume it has something to do with the fact that memory cache is a singleton instance and something goes wrong because I inject in two different places. What am I doing wrong and how can fix it so that TryGetValue doesn't return false when I expect it to return true?

Comment: your root page is running before your auth completes so it will always be null, you need to wire up a authentication state provider and wait for auth to complete

Comment: @fuzzybear, when I run my web app it opens to this screen and redirects me to the sign in page as expectend. When I sign in and then proceed to navigate back to the root screen it redirects me to the sign in page again. But in the second case the authentication has already been completed.

Comment: if we remove auth from the equation and set the cache, is it there ?

Comment: @fuzzybear, sorry for the delay. Yes, when I set it before the TryGetValue, it is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that MemoryCache is temporary storage during the lifetime of the program. Instead I used localStorage and this was the solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).